# SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to use this SQL query to generate some test data

```
    INSERT INTO EVENT (ID, SOURCE, TYPE, EVENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (DBMS_RANDOM.Value(5000, 90000), 101, 'WARNING', (SYSDATE - 1/10 + LOOP_COUNTER/1300), DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', 5))

CREATE TABLE EVENT(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
```

I get error Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"

Do you have any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What is `LOOP_COUNTER`? Could you share the entire context of this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Column SOURCE is a type of varchar2 but you are providing an integer

Comment: In this case Oracle makes implicit type conversion. It is not a reason of the error.

Answer (score 4):

Such error appears when you use unidentified variable in `VALUES` clause. Probably your variable `LOOP_COUNTER` is not declared or is written with a typo.

Answer (score 0):

We recently ran into this error while implementing some complex array binding logic and my team spent ages trying to figure out why were getting this error - we thought the keyword was the problem (our column lists are created by the business for each client and are dynamic per table).  Of course, it was something silly.

If you are doing array binding, when you setup the query make sure that all the fields in the values list have a ":" in front of them, this is what caused our error (note CompanyCode field):

```
string query = "INSERT INTO SURVEY.COMPANY (RPT_INDUSTRY,SUBMISSIONID,COMPANYCODE,COLUMN) VALUES (:RPT_INDUSTRY,:SUBMISSIONID,COMPANYCODE,:COLUMN)"
command.CommandText = query;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.BindByName = true;
```